# resize image without imresize (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, pixel

How to resize an image without using imresize in matlab

Comment: having someone to do your homework wont teach you matlab... If you spend 20-30 minutes reading through the basic documentation regarding matrix operations, notations etc, you'd be surprised how easy it all is...

Comment: Look at Richard Alan Peters II's image processing slides on image resampling: https://ia600307.us.archive.org/7/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE253_12_Resampling.pdf - Pay specific attention to slide #34.

Comment: Since @lakesh has given you the code of nearest neighbor interpolation, why don't you try bilinear interpolation and try to impress your teacher (and yourself!)?

Comment: Here's my implementation of bilinear interpolation in MATLAB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/how-to-shrink-an-image-without-using-imresize-function-in-matlab/26143655#26143655

Answer (score 8):

This code is done using nearest neighbor interpolation.

```
%# Initializations:

scale = [2 2];              %# The resolution scale factors: [rows columns]
oldSize = size(inputImage);                   %# Get the size of your image
newSize = max(floor(scale.*oldSize(1:2)),1);  %# Compute the new image size

%# Compute an upsampled set of indices:

rowIndex = min(round(((1:newSize(1))-0.5)./scale(1)+0.5),oldSize(1));
colIndex = min(round(((1:newSize(2))-0.5)./scale(2)+0.5),oldSize(2));

%# Index old image to get new image:

outputImage = inputImage(rowIndex,colIndex,:);
```

You just need to change the scale factor accordingly..

Comment: This is good code lakesh, but I wouldn't have posted this because the question sounds like homework.  We should let these people do their own homework.  I only give solutions if I can clearly see that they have made a good effort and are stuck.  This OP hasn't tried anything.  I will still vote +1 because this is the correct way to do nearest neighbour interpolation in 2D... or at least one of the correct ways.

Comment: I actually found this answer very helpful. MathWorks is very stingy with toolboxes, and it seems silly to pay for the Image Analysis toolbox just so you can scale an image.

Comment: Consider trying the FEX file https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44538-videoresize